# multiple model validation cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, model, save

i am using the latest cakephp2. In one controller, i have multiple action.

For exemple

```
OrderController.php

public function save_1(){
  //check validate of model and save
}

public function save_2(){
  //check validate of model and save
}
```

In the model:

```
Order.php

public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please enter Name'
    )
);
```

In the function save_1 of my controller, i need to check the name. That work.

But in the save_2 function, i have only to check the adress.

How can i make multiple validation with only 1 model ?

Thank you for your answer and sorry for my english ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Multivalidatable behavior in your model. Below is the link.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model

Thanks..!